# What is the proper way to cache fonts on an angular app

Tags: css, angular, caching, browser-cache, webfonts

I'm building an online photoshop-mini-like web app using `Angular`, for the sake of decreasing the load time, especially the fonts where I thought about fetching them from my backend (Google fonts don't include all the needed fonts).

So, what I really want is to cache each font a user chooses to use, so when he switches back to a loaded font the application won't fetch the backend for an existing one.

What I thought about is using [fontFaceObserver](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) a Webfont loading. Simple, small, and efficient. But, I didn't find a way to cache the fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use PWA? then you would cache all assets on the client side (service worker).
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

However, you need to have signed SSL certificate